# Ruby YAML::load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm trying to modify the default deserialization of the built-in timestamp format, to affect Ruby's Time.

I do this (successfully) with Hash:

```
YAML::add_domain_type('yaml.org,2002', 'map') { |t, v| nil }
YAML::add_domain_type('ruby.yaml.org,2002', 'hash') { |t, v| nil }
hash = { :hello => :world }
puts YAML::load(hash.to_yaml) # nil
```

But when I try the same with Time, it doesn't work:

```
YAML::add_domain_type('yaml.org,2002', 'timestamp') { |t, v| nil }
YAML::add_domain_type('ruby.yaml.org,2002', 'time') { |t, v| nil }
puts YAML::load(Time.now.to_yaml).class # 'Time'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of the very first line, `YAML::add_domain_type('yaml.org,2002', 'map') { |t, v| nil }` because if you remove that, the hash doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but YAML is failing to roundtrip Time objects according to http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/4005

Comment: Reference for [YAML::add_domain_type](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/class/yaml_add_domain_type_method.htm).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Psych (which is YAML in ruby 1.9.3p194) then you need to define an `encode_with/1` method on the Time class.

```
require 'yaml'

class Time
  def encode_with(coder)
    coder.tag = '!ruby/time'
    coder.scalar = to_s
  end
end

YAML::add_domain_type('ruby.yaml.org,2002', 'ruby/time') { |t, v| "HELLO!!" }

yaml = YAML.dump(Time.new)  # -> "--- !ruby/time 2012-10-25 14:18:59 -0400\n...\n"
YAML.load(yaml)  # -> "HELLO!!"
```

If the `encode_with/1` method is defined on the object then Psych calls that method passing in an instance of the `Psych::Coder` class; otherwise, it calls the `visit_#{o.class}` method in the `YAMLTree` class, which in the case of `visit_Time` does not serialize any tag information.

https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#l100-105

https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#l172-175